# Convert Data format in python to ascii

Tags: python, pandas, ascii

Data from Allen Bradley PLC comes in the format of 5 digit numbers in column 'value'

```
| tagid | value | datetime                | quality |
|-------|-------|-------------------------|---------|
| T0    | 21328 | 05-03-2021 14:11:53.087 | 192     |
| T1    | 12340 | 05-03-2021 14:14:25.787 | 192     |
| T2    | 17992 | 05-03-2021 14:16:52.687 | 192     |
| T0    | 17992 | 05-03-2021 14:19:14.470 | 192     |
| T1    | 17992 | 05-03-2021 14:21:31.623 | 192     |
| T2    | 21328 | 05-03-2021 14:23:50.220 | 192     |
| T0    | 21328 | 05-03-2021 14:26:13.747 | 192     |
| T1    | 17992 | 05-03-2021 14:28:29.817 | 192     |
| T2    | 17992 | 05-03-2021 14:31:03.603 | 192     |
```

Initially was i not able to recognize the steps to fetch desired value from this 5 digit value.

Then after some experiments in Excel/Python I did following steps and got the correct desired value

Steps: 
Step 1. Divide value by 256 and round (Eg 17992/256 which is 70 
Step 2. Do Mod the same value (Eg: =Mod(17992,256) which is 72
Step 3. Find Ascii value equitant to 70, which is F 
Step 4. Find Ascii value equitant to 72, which is H 
Step 5: Concatenate F& H which is FH

So the desired value for say 17992 is 'FH' , 12340 is '0468'

```
| tagid | value | datetime                | quality |
|-------|-------|-------------------------|---------|
| T0    | FH    | 05-03-2021 14:11:53.087 | 192     |
| T1    | 02    | 05-03-2021 14:14:25.787 | 192     |
```

Is there any simple and efficient method in python data frame to do above steps, instead of doing step by step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `apply` method to apply a function throughout a DataFrame (or Series).

```py
df['value_converted'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: chr(round(x / 256)) + chr(x % 256))
```

Comment: Thanks! Can i know what is the data type of the column 'value' which i got from PLC. just for understanding

Answer (score 2):

- simple integer **div** and **mod**
- `apply()` to series to get ASCII code

```
df.value = (df.value//256).apply(chr) + (df.value%256).apply(chr)
```

|  | tagid | value | datetime | quality |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | T0 | SP | 05-03-2021 14:11:53.087 | 192 |
| 1 | T1 | 04 | 05-03-2021 14:14:25.787 | 192 |
| 2 | T2 | FH | 05-03-2021 14:16:52.687 | 192 |
| 3 | T0 | FH | 05-03-2021 14:19:14.470 | 192 |
| 4 | T1 | FH | 05-03-2021 14:21:31.623 | 192 |
| 5 | T2 | SP | 05-03-2021 14:23:50.220 | 192 |
| 6 | T0 | SP | 05-03-2021 14:26:13.747 | 192 |
| 7 | T1 | FH | 05-03-2021 14:28:29.817 | 192 |
| 8 | T2 | FH | 05-03-2021 14:31:03.603 | 192 |